# bind different value to ng-model on some condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-show

I have started using Angular and don't have much experience in it.
I am stuck with an issue. I am using `ng-show` and `ng-model`.

its like

```
<tr ng-show="responseValid">
  <td> <input id="nameId" ng-model="model.name"/> </td>
</tr>
```

I am pre-populating the value in `model.name`.

Now if response is valid the input tag is shown otherwise not.

but when I `submit` the form, `nameId` value is bind by `ng-model="model.name`"

Issue here is I want `model.name` should not contain any value if response is not Valid i.e when input tag is hidden. but its not happening.

How can I `nullify/empty` the value in `model.name`? Is there anything available that I can use in the tag itself?

Comment: Do you want to clear the text from the Input tag in the   not valid case ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your send your model, check the state of the validResponse and set your model data based in this

example:

```
$scope.sendModel = function(){
  $scope.model.name = $scope.validResponse? $scope.model.name : '';
}
```

A more advanced example http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/mPzmxO

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` I believe.

`ng-if` removes elements from the DOM while `ng-show` only sets `display:none`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngSwitch or ngIf.

```
<tr ng-if="responseValid">
  <td> <input id="nameId" ng-model="model.name"/> </td>
</tr>
```

If the condition is not met, angular will completely remove the DOM element, till the condition will meet.